# Account ID for developer challenges

Tags: account, id

I just started getting into SalesForce last night. I am going through the *Visual Force Basics* and doing the examples after every section.

My problem is that I registered a developer demo account. I cannot find an Account ID to use for the examples.

I looked everywhere but I feel like there is not going to be one unless I am part of a company using SalesForce. Am I right or have I missed the account ID within my account?

Comment: The accountId that they refer to is the Id of an Account record in your system. If you look at the url bar for one of your accounts, you will see an alphanumeric value starting with `001`. If you put that number in the url for your visualforce page with `?id=001...` you will get it working.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Yes I am aware of what you are saying, I managed to find out this much by googling. However I have no account records in my system. I just signed up for a developer demo account. **EDIT** The ID for the user account that I have starts with 005 and I need an account id starting as you said with 001.

Is there a way to create an account record in my system and use that ID? I am still a little confused.

Comment: Sure, that's easy enough. Under the Account tab, you will find a button to create a new account. Click on that, save the account, grab the id and you're set.

Comment: Thank you again! Can you navigate me to that account tab? I swear I spent an hour looking things up and did not see such an option in my profile! **EDIT** Okay turns out I didn't have an Account tab. I finally noticed there was a + sign. After clicking there I saw the "accounts" option and created an account! Thank you, martin!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Account tab and hit New button, fill in all required fields, Save and you are done.

Comment: yes, thank you, Chiz! I just found that out. My problem was that I had no Accounts tab available in the top bar. It was hidden and I only revealed it by clicking on the "+" button. Hope that helps anybody else who might stumble upon the same issue!

Comment: I was going to add, that if you don't see it, you can do this (hit +) or select Sales application.

Comment: Yep, thank you, buddy! It's such a relief to get over this small issue so I can continue moving on.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a *Salesforce.com Organization ID*. You can find this ID on the "Company Information". Just go to Setup and then to "Company Profile > Company Information":

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I did try that earlier but it gives me an error "Id value is not valid for the Account standard controller ". The accound ID has to start with 001 as far as I read on a different website.